# Get indices from one randomly chosen true element in a boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a boolean array from which I would like the indices of one randomly chosen element that equals True. The output should be a tuple with the (x,y,z) indices of that element.

Is there a more elegant and/or efficient way to do this instead of doing the following?

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# create a random 3D boolean array
m = rng.choice(a=[False, True],size=(3,3,3))

# get (x,y,z) from one random cell in the boolean array which equals True
indices_where_true = np.where(m)
random_int = rng.randint(len(indices_where_true[0]),size=1)
random_index = (indices_where_true[0][random_int][0],
                indices_where_true[1][random_int][0],
                indices_where_true[2][random_int][0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.argwhere` instead of `np.where`:

```
true_idx = np.argwhere(m)

random_idx = rng.randint(len(true_idx),size=1)
random_index = true_idx[random_idx]
# array([[0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: This seems to be the most readable solution. Note that I ask for a tuple though, maybe you could add the following (or a better alternative) to your post: `random_index = true_idx[random_idx][0]
random_index = (random_index[0],random_index[1],random_index[2])`

Answer (score 0):

The note in the documentation for [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) states:

> When only `condition` is provided, this function is a shorthand for `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`. Using `nonzero` directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses.

So you should replace `where` with `nonzero`. After sampling a random integer you can pick the coordinates by taking all elements at that index along the first axis of `indices_where_true` using [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```py
from numpy import random
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# create a random 3D boolean array
m = rng.choice(a=[False, True],size=(3,3,3))

# get (x,y,z) from one random cell in the boolean array which equals True
indices_where_true = np.nonzero(m)
random_int = rng.randint(len(indices_where_true[0]),size=1)
random_index = np.take(indices_where_true, random_int, axis=1)
```